# Will any lubricant work on any treadmill?

Tags: treadmill

I bought the [LifeSpan TR1200-DT5 Treadmill Desk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006M2PJV0).  The manual says to use only 100% silicone lubricant.  Their product is overpriced, so I Googled "[100% silicone treadmill lubricant](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=100%25%20silicone%20treadmill%20lubricant)" to look for other products.  What do I see in almost every return result?  LifeSpan.  Now it seems like a marketing ploy to advise only to use 100% silicone.  Since  hardly any other treadmill explicitly requires that, anyone looking for 100% silicone lubricant will inevitably come across LifeSpan's product.

It seems to me that lube for one treadmill will work with another, but could I be wrong?

Comment: This question is off topic because it is about treadmill lubricant.

Comment: Is it? In Meta, we have questions about asking questions about equipment and it was ruled valid.

Answer (score 1):

Most hardware stores will sell silicone lubricant spray, it's the same stuff. Try Googling 100% silicone lubricant and leave out the word treadmill or ask at your local hardware for silicone lubricant spray. This is compatible with your treadmill, don't try non-silicone lubricants in case they eat at the belt.

Comment: Pretty much same results, but even more questionable now that LifeSpan still shows up numerous times even after removing the vital keyword "treadmill".  I also need non-aerosol according to the manual which, to me, seems legit.